# Javascript d3 pie chart doesn't pull data from JSON file with list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a .json file with data, and I'd like to make a d3 donut (pie) chart from it. I'm not especially fluent in javascript, and every example I can find either pulls from inline json data or the json file is structured differently than mine (mine is a list of dictionaries; theirs are often single dictionaries). I've been troubleshooting for a few days, and somehow can't land on anything that actually works. Any thoughts/tips?

The example at https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/donut_label.html uses inline json data to render a donut chart with labels. I've attempted to modify it that code by:

- pulling json data from /data/all-facet-digitized.json
- pull labels each dictionary's "facet" key ("true" and "false"), and values from each dictionary's "count" key (373977 and 55433).
- change the color scale domain to match the facet keys ("true" and "false")

/data/all-facet-digitized.json looks like:

```
[
  {
    "count": "55433",
    "facet": "true"
  },  
  {
    "count": "373977",
    "facet": "false"
  }
]
```

Code in the  of my html file looks like:

```
    <div id="chart"></div> <!-- div containing the donut chart -->


    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var width = 450
        height = 450
        margin = 40

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one) minus margin.
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

    // append the svg object to the div called 'chart'
    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


    // Parse the Data
    d3.json("/data/all-facet-digitized.json", function(data) {

      // set the color scale
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["true","false"])
        .range(d3.schemeDark2);

      // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
      var pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
        .value(function(d) {return d.count; })
      var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

      // The arc generator
      var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)

      // Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
      var outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)

      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      svg
        .selectAll('allSlices')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.facet)) })
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .style("opacity", 0.7)

      // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
      svg
        .selectAll('allPolylines')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('polyline')
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .style("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1)
          .attr('points', function(d) {
            var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
            var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
            var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
            var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
            posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
            return [posA, posB, posC]
          })

      // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
      svg
        .selectAll('allLabels')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
          .text( function(d) { console.log(d.facet) ; return d.facet} )
          .attr('transform', function(d) {
              var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
              var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
              pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
              return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
          })
          .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
              var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
              return (midangle < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
          })
      })

    </script>
```

My result renders as an empty space:

```
    <div id="chart">
      <svg width="450" height="450">
        <g transform="translate(225,225)"></g>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `schemeDark2` doens't exist in d3 v4. I've replaced it with `schemeCategory10`:

```
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["true","false"])
    .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Since you have an array of objects, you don't need `d3.entries`. That takes an object and converts it to an array where each key is an item of the array. But since you already have an array here, you can put it directly in `pie()`:

```
  // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
  var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
    .value(function(d) {return d.count; })
  var data_ready = pie(data)
```

Now that you've got the data, you can access it on any of the functions: try putting `console.log(data_ready)` to see what's available. You'll see that the data is bound for each object as the `.data` property. `pie()` takes an array and puts it in a format that's convenient to make pie charts with.

Say we want to access the facet property: we would access that as `item.data.facet`. So in your functions, to access, you can do:

```
  svg
    .selectAll('allSlices')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.facet)) })
```

```html
<head></head>
<div id="chart"></div> <!-- div containing the donut chart -->


    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var width = 450
        height = 450
        margin = 40

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one) minus margin.
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

    // append the svg object to the div called 'chart'
    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


    // Parse the Data
    var data = [
    {
      "count": "55433",
      "facet": "true"
    },  
    {
      "count": "373977",
      "facet": "false"
    }
]
      // set the color scale
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(["true","false"])
        .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

      // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
      var pie = d3.pie()
        .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
        .value(function(d) {return d.count; })
      var data_ready = pie(data)
      console.log('data_r', data_ready)

      // The arc generator
      var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)

      // Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
      var outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
        .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)

      // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
      svg
        .selectAll('allSlices')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.facet)) })
        .attr("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px")
        .style("opacity", 0.7)

      // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
      svg
        .selectAll('allPolylines')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('polyline')
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .style("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1)
          .attr('points', function(d) {
            var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
            var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
            var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
            var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
            posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
            return [posA, posB, posC]
          })

      // Add the polylines between chart and labels:
      svg
        .selectAll('allLabels')
        .data(data_ready)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
          .text( function(d) {  return d.data.facet} )
          .attr('transform', function(d) {
              var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
              var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
              pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
              return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
          })
          .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
              var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
              return (midangle < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if I wrap in d3.json("/data/all-facet-digitized.json", function(data) {}

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the issues here is that you've completely missed how `data_ready` is structured after converting the JSON response. You might want to add `console.log(data_ready)` just after you set `data_ready` and inspect it in the console for better understanding of the following fixes.

First a color fix:

```java
       .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.value.facet)) })
```

Then a data fix:

```java
       .value(function(d) {return d.value.count; })
```

And lastly a label fix:

```java
       .text( function(d) { console.log(d.data.key) ; return d.data.value.facet } )
```

Your script should look like this:

```java
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 450
    height = 450
    margin = 40

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.json("/data/all-facet-digitized.json", function(data) {

// set the color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["true","false"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(function(d) {return d.value.count; })
var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data))

// The arc generator
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)

// Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9)

// Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
svg
  .selectAll('allSlices')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.value.facet)) })
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("opacity", 0.7)

// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
svg
  .selectAll('allPolylines')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('polyline')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr('points', function(d) {
      var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
      var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
      var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
      var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
      posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
      return [posA, posB, posC]
    })

// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
svg
  .selectAll('allLabels')
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
    .text( function(d) { console.log(d.data.key) ; return d.data.value.facet } )
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
    })
    .style('text-anchor', function(d) {
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        return (midangle < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I got errors with these that d.value doesn't exist. Changing the color fix to use d.data.facet, data fix to use d.count, and label fix to "{ return d.data.facet }" did the trick, though.

Comment: No problem. I assume the error came from combining Hugo Elhaj-Lahsen's answer with mine which will cause errors. His answer is sligtly better so use his.